# If conditions not applying to char constants. Char being ignored

Tags: c, if-statement, character, scanf, constants

I have written various programs using the if condition, and they always seem to work only when I am using integer or float constants. Whenever i use char constants, the if condition completely ignores it. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int age;
  char status,gender;

  printf("Enter age, marital status and gender");
  scanf("%d%c%c",&age,&status,&gender);

  if((status=='m')||
     (status=='u' && gender=='m' && age>35) ||
     (status=='u' && gender=='f' && age>25))
    printf("Driver is insured" );
  else
    printf("Driver is not insured");
}
```

For instance, if I enter status as `u`, gender as `m` and age as `38`, it yet says that driver is not insured. Here is a transcript:

```
Enter age, marital status and gender
39 u m
Driver is not insured
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: show the whole code, incl. constants declarations

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the indention.

Comment: as in? @MarkBenningfield

Comment: When you have a problem with `scanf`, inspect the return value... (`if (3 != scanf(...) { ...} `)

Comment: You're assuming that the variables are getting the values you expect.  Using a debugger to examine the actual values of the variables would be quite illuminating.

Answer (score 1):

Before checking for `if` condition make sure whether its scanning all inputs properly or not by printing all `input` variable.

Its buffering problem(`stdin` not cleared as after first input`(int)`, second input is `char` and then you HIT the `ENTER/White space` which is also a **valid character**)

```
scanf("%d%c%c",&age,&status,&gender);
```

replace with

```
scanf("%d %c %c",&age,&status,&gender); /** space after %c will consume whitespace or ENTER */
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the format specifiers you're using.

The `%c` format specifier to `scanf` consumes *any* single character, including white space characters.  So if your input is `39 u m`, then a space is stored in `status` and `u` is stored in `gender`.

You need to add a space before each `%c` to consume the whitespace:

```
scanf("%d %c %c",&age,&status,&gender);
```

Comment: Trivia note: With the `"%d%c%c"` format specifier, an input of `39um` would give the desired result.